# Elasticsearch shows missing and deleted docs after bulk insert

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, bulkinsert, elasticsearch-plugin

I've encounter a strange behaviour after make some _bulk insert into elastic index.

Lets say i have a millions of docs  , but for example I need only 227,768 docs to insert. 
so i'm inserting with a chunk of 50,000.

To increase performance i disable first the refresh interval with:

```
PUT agg_vit_2016-08-07/_settings
{
  "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : -1
    }
}
```

Before the insert , I check that I have no duplicates id.

Example of inserting bulk rows:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "agg_vit_2016-08-07", "_type" : "player", "_id" : "0" } }
    {"time":"2016-08-07T03:00:00Z","domain":"www.cbs.com","mt_id":472,"cb_id":0,"c_id":0,"master_domain":"472###www.cbs.com","child_domain":"0###www.cbs.com","combo_domain":"0###www.cbs.com","playerrequest":0,"playerload":1,"adrequest":0,"adload":0,"adview":0}
    { "index" : { "_index" : "agg_vit_2016-08-07", "_type" : "player", "_id" : "1" } }
    {"time":"2016-08-07T03:00:00Z","domain":"www.thebrick.com","mt_id":478,"cb_id":0,"c_id":0,"master_domain":"478###www.thebrick.com","child_domain":"0###www.thebrick.com","combo_domain":"0###www.thebrick.com","playerrequest":0,"playerload":3,"adrequest":0,"adload":0,"adview":0}
    { "index" : { "_index" : "agg_vit_2016-08-07", "_type" : "player", "_id" : "2" } }
    {"time":"2016-08-07T04:00:00Z","domain":"kisshealthandbeauty.com","mt_id":618,"cb_id":0,"c_id":0,"master_domain":"618###kisshealthandbeauty.com","child_domain":"0###kisshealthandbeauty.com","combo_domain":"0###kisshealthandbeauty.com","playerrequest":0,"playerload":20,"adrequest":0,"adload":0,"adview":0}
```

....

after stop inserting enable the refresh again with :

```
PUT agg_vit_2016-08-07/_settings
    {
      "index" : {
            "refresh_interval" : "1ms"
        }
    }
```

but when I query the final total count is wrong:

```
GET agg_vit_2016-08-07/_count
{
  "count": 199991,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

some statistics from elastic :

```
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_all": {
    "primaries": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 199991,
        "deleted": 27766
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 49856669,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 227757,
        "index_time_in_millis": 26347,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },....
      ....
 "merges": {
    "current": 0,
    "current_docs": 0,
    "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "total_time_in_millis": 0,
    "total_docs": 0,
    "total_size_in_bytes": 0,
    "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
    "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
    "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 209715200
  },
```

## My Problem

When i'm querying the docs count i have missing documents.(as output stat shows)

Don't understand what could be the problem ? ,

why I have deleted docs `"deleted": 27766`  , and besides this , additionally  9 documents are missing  `"count": 199991,`

Thanks!!

Vitaly

Comment: First of all, refresh set to `1ms` (1 millisecond) is a killer. You should set it to `1s` (the default). Secondly, it's not clear what you did. You wanted to insert 200000 documents? How many documents were in the indexing before your indexing process?

Comment: Ok, i'll return it to default 1s , the index was empty before. I want to add  227,768 docs as in question , but i got only 199,991 docs

Comment: Then something is wrong with your indexing process. Look at the statistics: `"index_total": 227757,` which shows that you didn't index `227,768` documents, but less (11 less documents). And because you have deleted documents, it seems you deleted some of them in your indexing process.

Comment: Perform a manual `_refresh` and then get the statistics (more complete ones... now you only showed `indexing` and `merges`).

Comment: thanks, generally what might be a causes of "deleted": 27766 docs ....? (e.g: duplicate ids, ...?)

Comment: An update to an existing document will result in a deleted document, because the old version of the document is deleted and the new version inserted basically.

Comment: @VitalyT Have u found any clues? Having the same issues...

Comment: Okey, found an insue, was indeed the duplicate ids while inserting. I was performing bulk insert in batches - the documents were loaded from mongodb and when a sort field is unset each `skip+limit` can result to duplicate entries.

Comment: @tenbits , thanks !!!